# Magento language changes when changing theme

Tags: magento, themes

When I install a new theme the language changes. Is the theme controlling the language in Magento? When I change back to default theme the language is correct and I can install another theme that works too but the some themes don't get the correct language. Can anyone tell me how I can correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin menu go to the

**System > Configuration,**

the first tab shown should be General and it includes a **Locale section**.

That is where you set a store's language. You can choose which store it applies to with the scope selection in the top left of the page.

Also you can [see here](http://www.hellothemes.com/support-category/getting-started/how-to-set-up-languages-magento/) graphical notation 
hope this will sure help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I've done but when i install mApple from Mage-World the language changes to english even if it was swedish when the default theme was choosen. WHen I change back to default theme again then the language again is swedish. I think the language in some way is controlled by the theme?

Comment: yes i think there would be some code in theme to set language pack in some files to use this theme. will please search in theme files ? and also i would suggest you to . will u please accept my answer  so some one can use our thread in future if they wants to do the samthing